# How can I add a custom command to Siri?

Tags: ios, siri

I want to develop an app that works with a Siri command such as "send tweet".

In brief, Siri should send data to my app, and my app process this data. After that, my app returns to Siri.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no public API for your app to create custom commands for Siri. You'll probably want to watch the [WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/) Keynote to see if they announce integration for apps with Siri.

Comment: How can ı use as a private api? I want to only try.

Comment: @ilkerulusoy To the best of my knowledge, we don't even know of a private API to do this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Siri is using another speech recognition service. There are a few good options. One that I have had success with in the past is Wit.ai.

Comment: My aim is that control my app with Siri.

Comment: Yes, I read your question. But since you cannot do that, I offered an alternative.